# Loop for counting in python

Tags: python-2.7, loops, math, scientific-computing

I have two variables of data (`BxHPF` and `ByHPF`), which are equall in number of data. I would like to make a loop, which takes first value of `BxHPF` and `ByHPF` compute them, then take next one from `BxHPF` and `ByHPF` and so on. For now I have:

So I though about this way:

```
Computing = (float(BxHPF[0])/float(ByHPF[0]))
Dat1 = math.degrees(Computing)*(-1)
```

In fact those equations give me correct result. But as I wrote I need to make a loop, which will count every pair from `BxHPF` and `ByHPF` with using those two variables `Computing` and `Dat1`.

To be exact `BxHPF` and `ByHPF` contain 266150 records each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credits to @user202729 who solved my problem. Thank you.

```
result = [math.degrees(x/y)*(-1) for x,y in zip(BxHPF,ByHPF)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you mean with "count", but if you just want to put that computation into a loop, do this:

```
result = []

for x,y in zip(BxHPF,ByHPF):
    result.append(math.degrees(float(x)/y)*(-1))
```

btw: you don't need to use `float` twice. Python does a "float division" if the dividend *or* the divisor is float

> Any idea on how to save it?

```
with open('output.txt') as f:
    f.write("\n".join([str(i) for i in result]))
```

Comment: Or alternatively, use list comprehension. `result = [math.degrees(x/y)*(-1) for x,y in zip(BxHPF,ByHPF)]`.

Comment: yeah, I didn't want to shoot with list comprehension as the op seems to be new to python

Comment: Why so much hate, I am a beginner. Is it difficult for you to politely answer a question? There is no need to downvote, my question.

Comment: @Hiddenguy I didn't downvote you. Yeah, stackoverflow is rough for beginners. Don't worry, it's getting better over time